# Xcode Fails to Launch iPhone Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I am attempting to launch the iPhone simulator from Xcode, but I keep getting the following error:

> Error from Debugger: Failed to launch simulator: Operation failed with underlying error: 4294967253.

I've found a number of posts where Xcode failed to launch the simulator, but none of them match the specific error code I'm receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why I didn't try this earlier, but installing the latest version of Xcode fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you got things solved senfo.  I've found that doing a full rebuild can work as well as checking your system console log for erroneous error message/warnings.  Xcode unfortunately seems to be rather poor at conveying errors when deployments fail to the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've had issues like this, Force Quitting the simulator from the dock (Alt-Right click), followed by Xcode seemed to do the trick. After doing that I could reload my project and it would run fine.

Failing that, I hear it might help to reboot your mac (though I've never needed to go that far).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, it never launches, period, so I can't even force it to quit. I've also rebooted several times, without success. Not knowing Xcode very well, I'm not even sure where else to look.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help - Could it be a problem with the path to the simulator itself? Has the simulator ever successfully launched? You should be able to launch the simulator via spotlight (cmd-space, type 'spotlight'). If it isn't appearing here it sounds like you've got Xcode installed but not the iPhone SDK (or the simulator bundled with the SDK).

Comment: No worries, I appreciate you replying. It did work, at one point. Somebody else borrowed the laptop. When I got it back, it no longer worked.